# want to create a tag for CALS

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

I've encountered a couple of questions (e.g. [xsl cals tables: span cells, using colspec, namest and nameend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408261/xsl-cals-tables-span-cells-using-colspec-namest-and-nameend); see also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xml+CALS+table) in the XML/XSLT arena regarding the processing of data in the [CALS table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CALS_Table_Model) format. For those not familiar with CALS (like me), it's helpful to have an entry in the tag wiki to direct people to more info; and for those who are familiar with it, a tag helps them find the questions that are up their alley. CALS was at one time described as "[the most widely adopted industry SGML representation for tables](http://web.archive.org/web/20110402011307/http://users.rcn.com/hwbingham/tables/calstbhs.htm)."

I just tried to create such a tag, but when I try, SO tells me I can't create a `cals` tag because there is already a `cal` tag; if I really want to do this, it says, raise a question on meta. So that's what I'm doing. The `cal` tag refers to the Composite Application Library, which has nothing to do with CALS.

So what happens next - is a moderator supposed to come along and approve or reject this new tag proposal?

### Update:

I went ahead and used the `cals-table` tag, as @tohecz hinted, and edited the tag wiki entry for it. That edit is in the review queue. So I guess if that gets approved, I'll see whether `cals-table` starts showing up in the autocomplete list.

I could close this question, but I'm curious to hear more about why I couldn't find `cals-table` in the tag autocompletion list when I typed `cals`. How would I find out that such a tag existed?

Comment: [tag:cals-tables]?

Comment: @tohecz: I guess that worked. I'm a bit confused about whether that tag existed already. It didn't show up in the autocompletion list, unlike `local-storage` etc. However when I tried to tag the question with `cals-tables`, SO didn't warn me about creating a new tag. So did it already exist? But didn't show up because it has no wiki entry? Either way, it's confusing behavior...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I said in the comment, [cals-tables](/questions/tagged/cals-tables) is a good choice for this case.

Comment: Indeed it is. Thanks for the helpful tip. But I'm also curious how to know, next time, that such a tag exists.

Comment: Use the "type to find tags" box on http://stackoverflow.com/tags.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my last question... why didn't `cals-tables` show up in the autocomplete list of tags when I typed `cals`?

Because there's only room for 6 completions to be shown. And exact matches are not prioritized over fuzzy-and-often-irrelevant ones like `local-storage`. In this case, all 6 matches shown were irrelevant. All of them have something else before `cal`, e.g. `pascalstring`; and 5 of them have a hyphen between `cal` and `s`. Apparently, the popularity of those tags overrides the fact that the tag names were a poor fit to what I had typed.

One could advocate changes to those priorities, but that would be a separate conversation. E.g. **tag names with a match at the beginning of a word, and without hyphens in the middle, are likely to be better matches than others.**

Maybe what (else) we need is for the autocompletion list to give some **indication that it's not an exhaustive list** of possible completions, so that it didn't lead users to think there was no other tag containing the string they typed. E.g. a link labeled [Find other tags matching 'cals'...](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=name).

Comment: +1 tomorrow (limit reached), and this would make a nice [meta-tag:feature-request] as well, even though it's probably quite a lot of work with effect basically only to conincidence situations like this one.